# Binding graph to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: data-binding, datagrid, charts, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have displayed a DataGrid in my WPF project window, I also want a graph below it which takes the values from rows and columns and plots it.  I have been trying to do alot of things like binding graph to DataGrid but nothing seems to work. I am trying to do the following?

```
           <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=DgChem0}"> >
             <chartingToolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,65,0,0" Name="chart1" Title="Chart Title" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path= GlobalWarming}" IndependentValueBinding ="{Binding Path=ChemicalName}" />
             </chartingToolkit:Chart>
           </Grid>
```